# Как запустить скрипт для другой Таблицы

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Можно ли запустить скрипт для другой таблицы?

На родительской таблице есть скрипт, который читает из ячейки информацию и подставляет ее в новой строке. Дальше создается копия данной таблицы.

Необходимо чтобы скрипт вносил данные не только для новой таблицы, но и копировал те же данные в родительскую и запускал тот же скрипт, который добавляет строку.

Answer (score 1):

Нет никаких "родительских" Таблиц. Существует только контейнер или не существует. Обо всем об этом написано и в официальной документации и в описании к тегу на этом форуме. Не уверен, что есть смысл описывать механизм запуска скриптов из скриптов.

В данном случае вам необходимо перестраивать ваше приложение. Для манипуляции не активными Таблицами вам достаточно получить ссылку на них:

```
var someSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
```